# Apex helper class to create two opportunities

Tags: apex

I am trying to write a trigger and helper class for an Account that has the Type as "Prospect".  If the Account is updated and has no related Opportunities, two new Opportunities are added to the Account.  I have not had any luck getting the code to work.

Here is my Trigger:

```
trigger ResComOpportunityTrigger on Account (after update) {
    if(Trigger.isAfter && Trigger.isUpdate){
        ResComOpportunityHelper.UpdateOpps(Trigger.new);
    }
}
```

Here is my helper class:

```
public with sharing class ResComOpportunityHelper {

    static public void UpdateOpps(List<Account> acctList) {

        List<Opportunity> updateOppsList = new List<Opportunity>();

        acctList = [
                SELECT Id, Name, OwnerId, (SELECT Name, Id FROM Opportunities)
                FROM Account
                WHERE Type = 'Prospect'
        ];

        for (Account accUp : acctList) {
            for (Opportunity opp : accUp.Opportunities) {
                if (opp.Name == null) {
                    Opportunity opp1 = new Opportunity();
                    opp1.Name = 'Default Residential Opp';
                    opp1.AccountId = accUp.Id;
                    opp1.CloseDate = System.today().addMonths(3);
                    opp1.StageName = 'Prospecting';
                    updateOppsList.add(opp1);

                    Opportunity opp2 = new Opportunity();
                    opp2.Name = 'Default Commercial Opp';
                    opp2.AccountId = accUp.Id;
                    opp2.CloseDate = System.today().addMonths(3);
                    opp2.StageName = 'Prospecting';
                    updateOppsList.add(opp2);
                }
            }
        }
        insert updateOppsList;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The flaw in your logic is where you check if there are no child `Opportunities`.

**Incorrect**

```
for (Opportunity opp : accUp.Opportunities)
{
    if (opp.Name == null)
    {
        // add new child records to list
    }
}
```

**Correct**

```
if (accUp.Opportunities.isEmpty()
{
    // add new child records to list
}
```

Comment: Thank you Adrian.  I was looking for instructions on how to place the code language in a gray box (like you did).  Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: @robertlangedc You can always poke around the [help] for this sort of question or ask in [meta], but specifically here you needed to look for **[`formatting`](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/formatting)**. There is also an [advanced editing](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/editing-help) help page. Welcome to SFSE!